# roman numbering not showing correctly

Tags: numbering, arabic, text, page

I write a small arabic text document. I set the page numbering type to roman. 
When I use headings page style, I got the numbering correct in the center of the footer. But when changing the page style to myheadings, I got the page numbering in the top right of the page but in strange font (arabic font I presume) not roman !!!
could you help in having the numbering in roman at the top right of the page ?
Thanks in advance

Below the code :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic, english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\selectlanguage{arabic}
خلَق توفر الهواتف الذكية الحديثة 
\textLR{HAR}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how is the myheadings style defined?